# Boot from within windows

Tags: 64-bit, live-usb

I'm trying to follow these instructions on [using qemu to boot linux from within Windows](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/use-qemu-to-boot-linux-from-windows/). I downloaded `ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso` from this site, but it doesn't seem to run.

I have an Intel 64-bit processor (the i5 - 3570) and I just noticed the file is for AMD? But it was recommended to get a 64-bit processor.

Comment: you will do better if you download Ubuntu iso from [official source](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), and then **extract** the image into your usb drive.

Comment: `amd64` works fine for Intel 64-bits CPUs as well. It's called `amd64` because AMD released the first `x86_64` CPU (64-bit with  32-bit compatibility). Could you tell us what your problem is exactly? Are you getting an error?

Comment: That tutorial is very old. Look at this answer for some pointers on getting started using qemu. (Please upvote if helpful ;)

Comment: i want to run linux from within windows to read and write to ext 4 partitions. i've come across virtual box but it looks to complicated and installs files , i prefer portability of linux from usb

Error message "this kernel requires an x86-64 cpu, but only detected an i686 cpu.
unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your cpu"

Btw i am aware there are a few apps that supposedly read/write ext 4 partitions from windows, but the documentation even states they are unreliable at ext 4 and use with your own risk, I have tried them and they just don't work and are rubbish.

Comment: Then are you sure you have chosen x64 cpu in qemu?

Comment: Try http://archive.siejak.pl/fsproxy/wikka8979.html?wakka=HomePage&show_comments=1  FSProxy it does all qemu job for you and mounts ext4 via samba :)

Comment: you don't "choose x64" the entire process is automated, you just run the bat file with the iso in the drive. Which is why I like the simplicity of that compared to virtual box, which is installing several things and configuring more files.

Answer (score 2):

Actually `amd64` refers to 64-bit architecture in general. It's the same for both Intel x86_64 and Amd chips.

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but you may want to look into using more full-featured virtual machine software like VMWare Player or Virtualbox. Both are free.